# Javascript search for substring

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, string

Apologies as this is a repost of a thread I can no longer access or comment on.

I am trying to write a javascript function that will search all of the specified divs in a html page for the substring contained in my search bar. How can I do this simply?

Here is my code so far, I have it working so that the `showMe` method will only display the divs selected, I just need the substring code to work now. Could someone please help?

```
   <html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function dynamicSearch() {
    var val = document.getElementById('search').value;
    if (val == '')
      val = '-1';
    var srch = new RegExp(val, "gi");
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
    for (var idx in els) {
      if (idx != parseInt(idx))
        continue;
      var el = els[idx];
      if (typeof(el.innerHTML) !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(el.innerHTML);
        if (srch.test(el.innerHTML)) {
          el.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          el.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
  }

function showMe (it, box) { 
var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none"; 
document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;
} 

</script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
<label for="search">Search:</label>
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" onkeyup="dynamicSearch()"/>

<input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value1" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" />value1

<input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value2" onclick="showMe('div2', this)" />value2

<input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value3" onclick="showMe('div3', this)" />value3

<input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value4" onclick="showMe('div4', this)" />value4

<input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value5" onclick="showMe('div5', this)" />value5

<div class="row" id="div1" style="display:none">Show Div 1</div>
<div class="row" id="div2" style="display:none">Show Div 2</div>
<div class="row" id="div3" style="display:none">Show Div 3</div>
<div class="row" id="div4" style="display:none">Show Div 4</div>
<div class="row" id="div5" style="display:none">Show Div 5</div>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

The code I have here runs correctly for my checkboxes, but I cannot get it to only display the searched for substring as a result(ie the DynamicSearch function does not work, but the showMe one does...or at least I cannot get the DynamicSearch code to work?)

Comment: Unless you have some specific reason void avoiding it, please *please* consider jQuery or some other library for DOM traversal/manipulation. Also, the need for wrapping your scripts in HTML comment tags (`<!-- -->`) has passed, you shouldn't do that anymore, and you especially shouldn't omit the leading `//` on your opening `<!--` tag, that's a JavaScript parsing error.

Comment: I am open to using JQuery, I just cannot get the function to work properly (see my comment to the answer below). I think I have fixed the other problems you posted up now. Thanks a lot for the response.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with a simple loop?

```
function doSearch() {
 var val = $('searchBox').value;
 var els = document.getElementsByClassName('theDivs')
 //OR SIMILAR, whatever you need
 //var els = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
 for (el in els) {
  if (el.innerHTML.indexOf(val) >= 0)
   el.style.display = 'block'
  else
   el.style.display = 'none'
 }
}
```

EDIT: See this Fiddle - based off of your other fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nLxc4/5/

Comment: One of the answers I got on my other question was similar to this,  the problem being that if you specify that you only wish to get results from Div 1, then enter a substring of any other div, it is displayed, so it doesn't really work. I wouldn't mind using JQuery, I am just struggling to get it to work fully on my site. The link to the code posted previously is here http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/nLxc4/ . I just can't seem to get my head around fixing it.

Comment: So...you should only search divs if the respective checkbox is checked?

Comment: What I did was when a checkbox is clicked to 'active', set a class 'active' on the div while displaying it. Conversely, when unclikcing a check box, REMOVE the class of 'active'. Then, when a search term is entered, grab all elements of the class 'active' - NOT 'row'. Also, a blank search term was changed to a period, since that is a regex 'any' and a blank search should match anything.

Comment: For some reason, when I attempt to run this code on my home server, none of the divs are displayed, regardless of the settings I put in. Any ideas ? Thanks very much for your explanation, it all makes a lot more sense now ! :)

Comment: Not sure...Try using Chrome's Developer Tools or Firebug in Firefox (or even IE Developer tools if you REALLY have to) to see if any JS errors are being thrown.

Comment: I have a feeling I am linking in the JQuery incorrectly...does this look right to you? Sorry for all the questions : http://pastebin.com/C2BWz3fX

Comment: Sorry - I got pulled away yesterday and now your pastebin appears to have expired. I would suggest http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Setup if you think you are having issues getting jQuery into your server.